# In an array of buttons, how can you tell which button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, raphael

If I have an array of buttons, how can I tell which button was clicked? 
example below

```
 var i=0
 CreateButton = new function () {
    savebutton[i]=NewButton()
  i++
  }
```

every time a user runs the function a new button is generated.
the first button is `savebutton[0]` the second is `savebutton[1]` and so on potentially infinity times.

when later the user presses the button I want the screen to alert it's index number (or '`i`').

is there any way to make this work in arrays?

this : savebutton[i].click(alert(this))
and this: savebutton[i].onClick(alert(this))
do not work

the code is entirely written in RephaelJs and contains absolutely no DOM elements.

I use RaphaelJS and my HTML document contains no DOM elements. everything is scripted.

the entire function that generates the buttons:

```
var insertframe = function () {
            ww = WindowWidth
            mw = mywindoww
            zx = zone.getBBox().x
            zy = zone.getBBox().y
            zw = zone.getBBox().width
            zh = zone.getBBox().height
            sh = screen.getBBox().height
            sw = screen.getBBox().width
            py = picy
            px = picx
            srw = screenratiow
            srh = screenratioh


            savebutton[i] = paper.image(imageurl)


            savebutton[i].attr(
                             {
                                 'width': px * (framewidth * miniframesize) / zw,
                                 'height': py * (frameheight * miniframesize) / zh,
                                 'x': ((srw*520) + (i * 120) * srw) - zx * (frameheight * miniframesize) / zh,
                                'y': srh*600 - zy * (framewidth * miniframesize) / zw,
                                'clip-rect': (srw*520) + (i * 120) * srw + "," + srh * 600 + "," + framewidth * miniframesize + ',' + frameheight * miniframesize

                             })
            savebutton[i].click(alert(this))
            i++

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual, full code here?

Comment: I added the relevant function. the code is 500 lines that have nothing to do with this specific function. if my original "minimized" function would work I could easily incorporate it into the entire document. If you still feel that the entire document is absolutely crucial I will put it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the button, you can assign its index from the array as an attribute of the button and then when it's clicked on, you can examine that attribute of the clicked on button to see where it is positioned in the array.

If you don't want to do that, you can also search the array and find where the current button is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2d array with each element having an ID and an identifier. Can't say too much more without seeing your code.

Comment: if i could make an alert give the index number of any button that is pressed I can very easily make it do what ever I want. i'll add the entire function in an edit but, it is so filled with information that I think eventually it will makes things worse..

Answer (score 0):

I think JQuery might help you achieve that way easier. Check out this:
http://api.jquery.com/index/

Hope this helps!

Comment: It really got me excited for a moment but sadly i don't think this would work for infinity buttons since each button has to have a DOM element in the code (please correct me if i'm wrong)
really cool though!! thanks!